# extract data from google bucket

Tags: xml, google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook

I just received a link with datasets contained in a google bucket (it seems like a xml). I would like to extract the data using jupyter notebook but I don't know how to do it. I've been reading a lot about it but I still can't read the data.  Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: where are you going to run the Jupyter notebook ? on your machine , on google cloud ,

Comment: Hi marian-vladoi! I would like to run it on my local machine but it would be great if I can run it on GCS (I could learn both). I don't have experience reading data from cloud env.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your local environment,

- [Download gcloud SDK and install it](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install)
- Perform a `gcloud init` and then `gcloud auth application-default login`

***Please, don't generate and download a service account key file, as you will be able to see in many tutorials, it's a bad security practice when you can use your user credentials***

Then, in your notebook, you can use this piece of code

Import the library

```
%pip3 install google-cloud-storage
```

Then the code

```
from google.cloud import storage
client = storage.Client()
bucket = client.get_bucket('YOUR BUCKET NAME')
blob = bucket.get_blob('path/to/file.xxx')

# for text file
content = blod.download_as_string();
# for binary file
blod.download_to_filename('path/to/localfilename.xxx');
# You can use file writer (you can write in memory if you want, here in a filesystem)
with open('path/to/localfilename.xxx',w) as f:
  blod.download_to_file(f);
```

Does it work for you? If no, edit your question with your errors.